# LINQ return items in a List that matches any Names (string) in another list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have 2 lists. 1 is a collection of products. And the other is a collection of products in a shop.

I need to be able to return all shopProducts if the names match any Names in the products.

I have this but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
    var products = shopProducts.Where(p => p.Name.Any(listOfProducts.
             Select(l => l.Name).ToList())).ToList();
```

I need to say give me all the shopproducts where name exists in the other list.

Comment: Thanks everyone for there comments! I have it working now...  Thanks again.. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
var products = shopProducts.Where(p => listOfProducts.Any(l => p.Name == l.Name))
                           .ToList();
```

For LINQ-to-Objects, if `listOfProducts` contains many items then you *might* get better performance if you create a `HashSet<T>` containing all the required names and then use that in your query. `HashSet<T>` has O(1) lookup performance compared to O(n) for an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
var names = new HashSet<string>(listOfProducts.Select(p => p.Name));
var products = shopProducts.Where(p => names.Contains(p.Name))
                           .ToList();
```

For LINQ-to-SQL, I would expect (hope?) that the provider could optimise the generated SQL automatically without needing any manual tweaking of the query.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a join, for example:

```
var q = from sp in shopProducts
        join p in listOfProducts on sp.Name equals p.Name
        select sp;
```

A fuller guide on join is [here](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/JoinOperator.ashx).

Comment: I hate the 'special' linq syntax, but conceptually the join is probably the way to go with linq-to-sql. With linq to object I'm not so sure which would perform better.

Comment: Concerning linq-to-object - the query in this answer ultimately translates to an Enumerable.Join call, which according to the documentation has a hashed-lookup.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx - "The default equality comparer, Default, is used to hash and compare keys."

Answer (score 4):

You could create an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that says products with equal names are equal.

```
class ProductNameEqulity : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public bool Equals(Product p1, Product p2)
    {
        return p1.Name == p2.Name
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product product)
    {
        return product.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in the `Intersect` extension method.

```
var products = shopProducts.Intersect(listOfProducts, new ProductNameEquality());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this please

```
var products  = shopProducts.Where(m=> listOfProducts.Select(l=>l.Name).ToList().Contains(m=>m.Name));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var products = shopProducts
        .Where(shopProduct =>
                listOfProducts.Any(p => shopProduct.Name == p.Name))
        .ToList();
```