# Find the operator in string and get left and right word

Tags: c#

How can i find an operator in the string? After that, I'd like to create get the left and the right variable.

If the string was:

> DisengagementPoint=TravelForce

or

> DisengagementPoint=100

but some time string be longer like:

> DisengagementPoint=100 (VehicleSpeed>2)   || (EngineRpm== 0)

And I want to create a string with whatever is on the left side of "=" and one string with right side, how could I do that?

Output that I expected:

> var1 = DisengagementPoint
>
> var2 = 100 or TravelForce
>
> var3 = (VehicleSpeed>2)   || (EngineRpm== 0)

Sorry this is pretty pseudo, but hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: You could use `string.Split('=')` to get an array. Then `strArr[0]` is the left and `strArr[1]` is the right word.

Comment: Is `=` the only operator you care about?  How do you want to handle cases where it occurs  more than once?

Comment: for the variable between "("  ")" i use an interpreter

Comment: i think first i need to take out what is between () and make 2 string one with `DisengagementPoint=100` and one `(VehicleSpeed>2) || (EngineRpm== 0)`

Comment: @AdrianMoldovan: Why don't you update your question with expected ouput alongside the input?

Comment: @AdrianMoldovan This relates to the question you deleted of find a list of strings in a string (list) and might assist you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456577/linq-return-items-in-a-list-that-matches-any-names-string-in-another-list

Comment: I recommend throwing an existing parser for [context free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) at the problem. Or at least study techniques for parsing such grammars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like add two things to other excelent answers:

A) The `string.Split` splits the string by all equals thus `DisengagementPoint=100` would go out just fine but `line = "DisengagementPoint=100 (VehicleSpeed>2) || (EngineRpm== 0)"` would get quite messy since just splitting with string `string[] split = line.Split('=')` would yield array:

```
split[0] = "DisengagementPoint"
split[1] = "100 (VehicleSpeed>2) || (EngineRpm"
split[2] = ""
split[3] = " 0)"
```

This can be eliminated by restricting maximal number of splits with `line.Split('=', 2)` returns maximally two sub-strings. And also `line.Split('=', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` could help to get rid if empty parts, but this would not be an issue in this case.

B) What with problem of comparison operator `==`? Perheaps check if there are only a single equals or more of them and if more, if there are at least two of them right behind themselves.

As mentioned in comment to @Dmitry Bychenko´s post by @AustinWBryan this starts to look parser problem, which is a bit different question in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Just find `=` position and take substrings:

```
String source = "DisengagementPoint=100";

int index = source.IndexOf('=');

// you may want to test if there's '=' in the string
// if (index >= 0) ...   

String left = source.Substring(0, index);
String right = source.Substring(index + 1);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for his later example of `DisengagementPoint=100 (VehicleSpeed>2) || (EngineRpm== 0)`

Comment: @AustinWBryan: what's the expected output for the `"DisengagementPoint=100 (VehicleSpeed>2) || (EngineRpm== 0)"`? My current code'll return `DisengagementPoint` and `100 (VehicleSpeed>2) || (EngineRpm== 0)`

Comment: first i think i need to split the string in 2 one with `DisengagementPoint=100` and one with `(VehicleSpeed>2) || (EngineRpm== 0)`

Comment: It's not very clear, but I believe he wants some expression tree, where all of the terms are stored by themselves; `str[0] = "DisengagementPoint", str[1] = "100", str[2] = "VechicleSpeed"`, etc., while maintining the order of operations, basically a parse

Answer (score 1):

```
var word = "DisengagementPoint=TravelForce";
var index = word.IndexOf("=");

if(index > 1)
{
    var left  = word.Substring(0, index);
    var right = word.Substring(index + 1,word.Length - index - 1);
}
```

As DmitryBychenko mentioned

```
var right = word.Substring(index + 1,word.Length - index - 1);
```

can be replaced with

```
var right = word.Substring(index + 1);
```

Comment: `word.Length-index-1` in the last `Substring` in redundant, `word.Substring(index+1);` is enough